# Kendo UI DropDownList Posts only DataValueField and not the object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using kendo dropDownList in Html.BeginForm. The problem is I can get only the DataValueField which is Id in my case. Why I don't get the object (DataTextField+DataValueField?)

Here is my dropDown:

```
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.Company)
                .OptionLabel(" ")
                .DataTextField("ComapnyName")
                .DataValueField("Id")
                .Filter("contains")
                .DataSource(source =>
                {
                    source.Read(read =>
                    {
                        read.Action("GetCompanies", "ReportSingleUser");
                    })
                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                })
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DataValueField is an identifier you can use to get the Text field  from the database.

If you need the text from the client side use jQuery

```
$("#yourdropdownid option:selected").text();
```

for Kendo UI

```
  $("#yourdropdownid").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
```